# image in an Expanded TableViewCell is lost after scrolling

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

I am creating an application in which i have many table cells(>300). I have successfully implemented expanding and collapsing tableview cells. On expansion an image is displayed which is fetched from a webservice, on clicking the expanded cell, the cell collapses again, if another cell is clicked the previous cell collapsed and current cell expands. Now the problem is if the user scrolls the tableview with the cell expanded table works fine but when he returns
to it the image gets lost, and there is a bit of problem with the functionality as well( the table takes that cell to be collapsed).

Moreover if the user keeps on scrolling the table down he can encounter that image in a collapased cell(which looks very bad), i think its because dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is fetching the already expanded cell.

PS: Every image is different based on the cell value but it is fetched in  a different call(not al together ie to fetch 300 images i make 300 independent calls).

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UIImageView * imageView;
    UILabel     * nameLabel;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45.0, 5.0, 245.0, 34.0)];
        nameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:CELL_FONT size:CELL_FONT_SIZE];
        nameLabel.tag = 2;
        nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:nameLabel];
        [nameLabel release];

        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, 5.0, 30.0, 30.0)];
        imageView.tag = 1;
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
        [imageView release];
    }
    else {
        imageView = (id)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
        nameLabel = (id)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    }

    return cell;
}
```